# Multithread python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

For my bachelor thesis I need to grab some data out of about 40000 websites. Therefore I am using python requests, but at the moment it is really slow with getting a response from the server.

Is there anyway to speed it up and keep my current header setting? All tutorials I found where without a header.

Here is my code snipped:

```
def parse(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    for line in r.iter_lines():
        ...
```

Comment: How about using `multiprocessing`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393617/python-requests-module-multithreading

Comment: @bsa no need for multiprocessing, the overhead of new process is too big, threads are better for io bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can use threads since this is a **I/O Bound** problem. Using the built in `threading` library is your best choice. I used the [`Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects) object to limit how many threads can run at the same time.

```
import time
import threading

# Number of parallel threads
lock = threading.Semaphore(2)


def parse(url):
   """
   Change to your logic, I just use sleep to mock http request.
   """

    print 'getting info', url
    sleep(2)

    # After we done, subtract 1 from the lock
    lock.release()


def parse_pool():
    # List of all your urls
    list_of_urls = ['website1', 'website2', 'website3', 'website4']

    # List of threads objects I so we can handle them later
    thread_pool = []

    for url in list_of_urls:
        # Create new thread that calls to your function with a url
        thread = threading.Thread(target=parse, args=(url,))
        thread_pool.append(thread)
        thread.start()

        # Add one to our lock, so we will wait if needed.
        lock.acquire()

    for thread in thread_pool:
        thread.join()

    print 'done'
```

Comment: What if a website is multiple times in that 40000 website list? (If I need data from more then 1 page) How can I not ddos them? Just waiting a random time before a request?

Comment: You will have to use dict: the keys will be the website's URL and the value will be `Semaphore` lock. That a bit more complicated. if the answer is right please accept it, thanks :) @QDA

Answer (score 0):

You can use asyncio to run tasks concurrently. you can list the url responses (the ones which are completed as well as pending) using the returned value of `asyncio.wait()` and call coroutines asynchronously. The results will be in an unexpected order, but it is a faster approach.

```
import asyncio
import functools


async def parse(url):
    print('in parse for url {}'.format(url))

    info = await #write the logic for fetching the info, it waits for the responses from the urls

    print('done with url {}'.format(url))
    return 'parse {} result from {}'.format(info, url)


async def main(sites):
    print('starting main')
    parses = [
        parse(url)
        for url in sites
    ]
    print('waiting for phases to complete')
    completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(parses)

    results = [t.result() for t in completed]
    print('results: {!r}'.format(results))


event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    websites = ['site1', 'site2', 'site3']
    event_loop.run_until_complete(main(websites))
finally:
    event_loop.close()
```

Comment: What if a website is multiple times in that 40000 website list? (If I need data from more then 1 page) How can I not ddos them?

Comment: Will using `repeat` from `itertools` help? `from itertools import repeat`; `websites.extend('sitex', 100)`. What exactly is your need? Are you setting up the pages separately and dynamically ? This repeat only helps in appending a particular website for a specific number of times.

Answer (score -1):

i think it's a good idea to use `mutil-thread` like `threading` or `multiprocess`, or you can use `grequests`(async requests) due to `gevent`